# when I use NavigatorIOS， why the init view is empty?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an iOS app with react-native and now I'm stuck trying to load init view with `NavigatorIOS`, my code is like this:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var { AppRegistry, NavigatorIOS, StyleSheet, Text, View } = React;

var Movies = React.createClass({
  render: () => (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  ),
});

var hot_moive = React.createClass({
  render: () => (
    <NavigatorIOS
      initialRoute={{
        title: 'Movies',
        component: Movies,
      }}
    />
  ),
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: '#333',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('hot_moive', () => hot_moive);
```

the resulting screenshot is:

[image]

I don't know why, please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Your text is probably hidden behind the navbar.

```
var Movies = React.createClass({
  render: () => (
    <View style={{marginTop: 64}}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  )
});
```